# How to convert present perfect to present continuous using python nltk

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

Using Python NLTK module, I want to convert `develop` to `developing`.

```
>>> nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('loving', 'v')
u'love'
```

This piece of code does the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think there is verb conjugations in NLTK bro. you can use [NodeBox](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation). Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NodeBox linguistic package.

```
import en
print en.verb.present_participle("love")
```

Output:

```
>>loving
```

You may want to read about verb conjugation for the package [here](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation).

Hope this helps.

Comment: better if you post the steps to install nodebox.. I already solved this problem through nodebox.. What I did is, downloaded nodebox linguistic package from the download link they mentioned and extracted the contents on a specific folder inside my project's directory..